# Is it safe to run docker-compose pull when restart policy is set to always

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am planing to use docker-compose to deploy the same application on multiple hosts. The application needs to automatically restart if it fails, so I want to use `restart: always` policy.

When deploying a new version, I need to pull the newest image and restart the services. However I would prefer this to happen on all host at the same time ( or as close as possible with this setup ).

To make the duration of the whole process as low as possible, I intend to run `docker-compose pull` on all hosts and wait for it to finish.

Once the pull is finished on all hosts, I would just restart the services with `docker-compose up -d`.

However, I am uncertain ( and I'm unable to find myself a definitive answer ), what will happen if, after I run `docker-compose pull`, a service crashes and auto-restarts. Will it auto-restart with the new image or the old image?

P.S. I'm aware that k8 and other orchestrators exists for exactly this purpose, however for the time being I consider them an overkill, and I would like to continue with ansible which we are internally comfortable with.

Answer (score 0):

A restart policy will not change the image underneath a container.

A container runs a single process.  `docker run` or `docker-compose up` will both create the container and start the process in it.  If the process stops for some reason, you can be in a state where the container still exists but it does not have a running process.  From this state, `docker start` will start the process again in the same container; a [restart policy](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#restart-policies---restart) does this for you automatically.

The important detail here is that the restart happens *in the same container*.  You cannot change the image underneath a container without deleting and recreating it, but a restart policy doesn't do this.

---

A common practice is to make sure each build of your application has a unique tag, and to avoid running a `latest` build.  (This is all but required in Kubernetes, but applies to other environments as well.)  In Compose you can use an environment variable, like

```yaml
image: registry.example.com/myapp:${MYAPP_TAG:-latest}
```

If you do that, then you can explicitly pull the new image

```bash
MYAPP_TAG=20230305 docker-compose pull
```

`docker images` will show the new image, but `docker ps` will more explicitly show the container is still running the old image.  Then running

```bash
MYAPP_TAP=20230305 docker-compose up -d
```

will delete the existing containers and create new ones with the new image.